# How to put my iframe elements in a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 10 `<iframe>` elements in my aspx page and they are named f1,f2,.......,f10. What I want to do is to put theme in a list/array so that I can reference them by index.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each control (your `Page` being one of them) has a `Controls` property that get a list of all sub-controls.

```
this.Controls; //will list all sub controls on the page
```

You can search through that for your items.

Alternately, you can use the [`FindControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) function on a `Control` object to get a control based on its ID.

```
var cnt = this.FindControl("f1");
```

Copy this line 10 times or make it in a loop, and make them add to an array:

```
List<Controls> iframeList = new List<Controls>();

for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    iframeList.Add(this.FindControl("f" + i);
```

Comment: Can I use for each in here instead of typing the iframeList.Add 10 times?

Answer (score 2):

```
var framearray = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"); 

for (var i = 0; i < framearray.length; i++) 
{ 
    var aframe = framearray[i]; 
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: @ChrisN.P. - sigh, being that you never specified that you wanted it in backend code, people started downvoting the two of us who provided client-based code solutions, that's kind of a big thing to leave out...

Comment: is there a way to correct the downvoting?... I fairly to this site

Comment: I'm sorry about this csuwldcat and gunr2171. This is not my intention. I thought when I put the tag c# or ASP.Net it will be clear enough to provide solution base from it. I tried to vote for your answer aswell csuwldcat but it doesn't allow me. Again I'm sorry for this.

Answer (score 1):

`<iframe>` elements are automatically indexed by the browser in a list object called `window.frames`, you can iterate this array-like object with a standard for() loop --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.frames

Comment: @gunr2171 - when I see "<iframe> elements", that naturally indicates client-side, unless I missed the part where C# has a DOM with elements... I figured he tagged it that way because it originated out of a C# aspx file.